# Solutions of $\sqrt{x^2+5x-14} + |x^2+4x-12|=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals, absolute-value

**My attempt:**

Given,

$$\sqrt{x^2+5x-14} + |x^2+4x-12|=0 \tag{1}$$

Since $|a|=\sqrt{a^2}$, $$\sqrt{x^2+5x-14}=-\sqrt{(x^2+4x-12)^2}$$

Squaring both sides, $$x^2+5x-14=(x^2+4x-12)^2$$

When I simplify the above, I get *two* real solutions: $x=2$ and $x=2.138 \text{ (approximately)}$. However, there is only *one* solution to equation $(1)$ according to Wolfram Alpha, $x=2$.

Is my solution incorrect? If so, where did I go wrong?

Comment: $y+2=6$ has one solution namely $y=4$, while $y^2+4y+4=36$ has two solutions $y=4$ and $y=-8$.  Squaring both sides of an equations can introduce a spurious solution

Comment: @Henry I thought that was causing the error. What's the correct way to solve this?

Comment: No reason to square both sides. If $a=-b$ with both $a,b$ non-negative, then $a=b=0.$

Comment: Note that this is the sum of two non-negative terms and so it can be 0 only when both terms are equal to 0 and this happens only when $x=2$

Comment: If you do square (or any other transformation which is not a bijection), it is worth checking your final solutions in the original equation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you square, you may get additional solutions. You need to test those solutions in the original equation.

Alternatively,

$\sqrt{x^2+5x-14} + |x^2+4x-12|=0$

$\implies x^2+5x-14 = 0 \ \text { and } x^2+4x-12 = 0$

$\implies (x-2) (x+7) = 0 \ \text { and } (x-2)(x+6) = 0$

So only solution that works is $x = 2$.

Answer (score 2):

Why not factorise first, since both quadratics clearly very easily factorise, into $\sqrt{(x+7)(x-2)} + |(x+6)(x-2)| = 0 \implies$
$\sqrt{(x+7)(x-2)} = -|(x+6)(x-2)| \implies $
$(x+7)(x-2) = ((x+6)(x-2))^2$

This very clearly only has one solution, being $x=2$, since both terms must be zero

Answer (score 2):

When you squared both sides, you generated candidate solutions that each had to be checked against the original equation.  As a simpler example:

$\sqrt{4} = x.$

Squaring both sides yields the equation $4 = x^2$, which has the two candidate solutions of $x = \pm 2.$  Each candidate solution must be checked against the original problem to see if it satisfies the problem.

More formally,
you have that if a value satisfies the original equation, and you square both sides, then the value will satisfy the new equation.  However, this is (in general) a one-way implication.  This means that the new equation may have (candidate) solutions that don't satisfy the original equation.

Answer (score 0):

Both $\sqrt{x^2+5x-14}\geq 0$ and $|x^2+4x-12|\geq 0$

So, both of them must equal to zero, since equation is equal to zero.

$$\sqrt{x^2+5x-14}= 0$$

$$x^2+5x-14=0$$

$x=-7$, or $x=2$

$$|x^2+4x-12|= 0$$

$$x^2+4x-12=0$$

$x=-6$, or $x=2$

Finally
$x=2$